13u baseball - single with base runner error or fielders choice?
Bases loaded, 1 out. The batter hits fly ball that drops in the gap. The runner at 3rd tagged up incorrectly and then was thrown out at home in a force out. Is this a single with a base-running error or a fielders choice?

Under MLB scoring rules, this is a fielder's choice, not a base hit.  Rule 9.05(b)(1) is:

(b) The Official Scorer shall not credit a base hit when a: (1) runner is forced out by a batted ball, or would have been
forced out except for a fielding error;

So if there's a force out, it's not a base hit.  It doesn't matter that the runner was only forced because of poor base-running, and that with "reasonable effort" base-running, everyone would have been safe.  There's no scoring provision for base-running errors.
It may be that you're playing under USSSA rules, but they don't appear to address scoring at all, and they say that MLB rules apply to any situation that USSSA rules don't cover.

How is it being determined that this scenario is being played under USSSA rules?

@рrоӏарs: Just a guess. The post said 13U, and USSSA seems to be a prominent organization at that level.

That's fair. I mention it because while rules/terms are likely to be the same, there may be a difference so I think your answer does a good job hedging bets in relation to that.
